# How to decide on dimension fields type

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-warehouse, cube

When I build my cube, what are the considerations for choosing dimension fields types, for instance customer number should I define it as string or numeric?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Do you have something specific or is it just a general "what if" question?

Comment: Starting point: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp

Answer (score 1):

If a customer number is a number it should be numerical, there are various types and the best place to start is. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp Then come back with a specific query or test and built a base and show the code/build.

Comment: I mean in general terms. For a dimension field that contains only numbers and i am indifferent about his type (its a dimension, therefore i am not going to do any "numerical" calculations on him, like sum, avg etc...). Is there a "best practice" for choosing a type for this kind of fields?

Comment: I am assuming because your creating a cube this is for reporting needs, which I am then going to assume is very fluid as requirements from the business will come continuously. Because of that, I'd make any numbers numeric. Right now you may know how your cubed data is going to be used, but a month or two or six later you won't.

Comment: Give the "Data Warehouse Toolkit" a read by Ralph Kimball.  It is pretty much the bible for data warehouse/cube building and what is considered "best practice"

Answer (score 0):

I generally put everything in string format.  Date Particularly.  Today your Customer number is a number.  But tomorrow if someone changes source systems and business decisions it could become a string.  So I generally try to setup the Data Warehouse structure to be as accommodating to business changes as possible with the least amount of data warehouse change needed.

I would then look for a data validation process to insure that the Customer Number is a number then if the business changes I can simply switch off that data validation process without changing my database structure or BI that depends on data types.

But I would also say there is no "right" answers here.  It is an engineering decision with advantages and disadvantages what ever direction you go.